# Audit Trail Error, Login Page Not Found

Tags: sitecore-client

I'm getting an error while opening the audit trail popup window, does anyone know how to fix this error? It got stop working suddenly.

[image]

- Sitecore version is: 10.1.0

Log error message:

```
ManagedPoolThread #0 19:35:40 WARN Number of suppressed logs due to the minimum time between log entries: 7
43932 19:35:41 ERROR No login page specified for current site: EchoPark (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)).
43932 19:35:41 ERROR SC Audit Trail For Item : System.Exception: No login page specified for current site: EchoPark (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)).
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method)
at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.RedirectToLoginPage(HttpContext httpContext, List`1 queryParametersToRemove)
at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Can you specify your Sitecore version and also anything you find in logs. please provide here.

Comment: @SumitBhatia I have updated the question with the logs and included the Sitecore version.

Comment: Is the audit trail a custom module?

Comment: It's a Sitecore plugin http://klpatil.github.io/Sitecore-Audit-Trail/ @MichaelWest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem as you. Referring to Sumit's reply, I have made the following modifications. Now it works for me. My Sitecore version is 9.3

1. Update the files as Sumit said. These files under `\<yoursiteroot>\Tools\AuditTrail`
2. Move the AuditTrail folder from `\<yoursiteroot>\Tools` to `\<yoursiteroot>\sitecore`
3. Update the `\<yoursiteroot>\App_Config\Include\SCBasics.AuditTrail.config`

[image]

**Note**: The above three steps are enough. Simultaneously, I found an incompatibility issue with multisite. So I have updated the `ForSite.aspx.cs` to fix it. If necessary, the following code for your reference:

```
public partial class ForSite : Sitecore.sitecore.admin.AdminPage
    {
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                    LoadSiteAuditTrailDetails(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["id"]));
            }
        }

        private void LoadSiteAuditTrailDetails(string ItemID)
        {
            SCAuditLogsDataContext scAuditLogsDataContext =
                new SCAuditLogsDataContext();

            Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            Item currentItem = masterDb.GetItem(ItemID);
            var currentSiteName = currentItem.GetContextSite().Name;

            IOrderedQueryable<Log> logs =
                scAuditLogsDataContext.Logs.Where(x => 
                    x.SiteName == currentSiteName).
                OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);

            if (logs == null && !logs.Any())
            {
                ShowMessage("No audit trail records found, it seems that you haven't configured SCAuditTrail or no actions recorded yet.",
                    "Error");
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                tblSCAuditTrailForSite.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {

                foreach (Log aLog in logs)
                {

                    if (aLog != null)
                    {

                        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                        tableRow.ID = "row" + aLog.ID.ToString();
                        tableRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;


                        //Action
                        SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.UIControlUtil.AddTableCell(tableRow,
                            aLog.SCAction,
                            SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.SourceTextType.Text);


                        //UserName
                        SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.UIControlUtil.AddTableCell(tableRow,
                             aLog.SCUser,
                             SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.SourceTextType.Text);

                        //Date
                        SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.UIControlUtil.AddTableCell(tableRow,
                            aLog.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString(),
                            SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.SourceTextType.DateTime);

                        
                        // ItemID
                        SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.UIControlUtil.AddTableCell(tableRow,
                            aLog.SCItemId,
                            SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.SourceTextType.Text,
                            aLog.SCItemPath);

                        //ItemLanguage
                        SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.UIControlUtil.AddTableCell(tableRow,
                            aLog.SCLanguage,
                            SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.SourceTextType.Text);

                        // ItemVersion
                        SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.UIControlUtil.AddTableCell(tableRow,
                            aLog.SCVersion,
                            SCBasics.AuditTrail.Utils.SourceTextType.Text);

                        tblSCAuditTrailForSite.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                    }

                }


                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                tblSCAuditTrailForSite.Visible = true;

            }
        }

        private void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get last error from the server
            Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Write("Oops something went wrong : " + exc.Message);
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("SC Audit Trail For Item : " + exc, this);
            Server.ClearError();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will be used
        /// to show message
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Message to show</param>
        /// <param name="messageType">Message type to show</param>
        private void ShowMessage(string message, string messageType)
        {
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = message;
            if (messageType == "Error")
            {
                lblMessage.CssClass = "alert alert-danger";

            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.CssClass = "alert alert-success";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, give me two days, I'm gonna try it and then I got back with the feedback.

Comment: Hey wsnow, it worked! It seems that I was having a problem with these files and the tools. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using hasn't been updated for 8 years and does not support the later versions of Sitecore.

We have used this on another project, I recall the update being quite minor (apart from updating `DLLs`, etc).

I think you need to update the files:

- `Foritem.aspx.cs`
- `Forsite.aspx.cs`
- `Forreport.aspx.cs`

To inherit from AdminPage rather than from SecurePage.

You can find the above files here within the plugin files:
https://github.com/klpatil/Sitecore-Audit-Trail/tree/master/Tools/AuditTrail

Comment: Hello Summit, thanks for the answer. But, I actually do not have this files :'(. Could you share the path where you have this files ?

Comment: Hi Fabio, I have updated my answer to show where these files can be located within the plugin